# Site not accessible over LTE but works fine over WiFi - AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have an EC2 server running WordPress, Cloudfront distribution and DNS configured through Route53.

**I have an extremely interesting problem.**

The site works fine over WiFi, but doesn't load over LTE (3G or 4G).

The DNS settings are as follows:

- A Record is an Alias pointing to the Cloudfront distribution
- AAA Record is also an Alias pointing to the Cloudfront distribution

> What am I missing here so that the website doesn't load over non-WiFi
>   connections?

Comment: could be that it is taking time to replicate your DNS entries to your ISPs DNS server.

Comment: Highly unlikely - I configured the Route53 over a year ago. I only just found out about this issue recently.

Comment: Yeah. Agree. Any WAF in front of CloudFront distribution? Does it happen with a specific telecom provider's network or with every? Do you get timeout or access blocked? What kind of error is returned when you are on LTE? What is the URL of the website?

Comment: @Asdfg WAF? It's not with a specific telecom provider, it's with all of them interestingly enough. The error is: A server with the specified hostname could not be found: NSURLErrorDomain.

Comment: Web Application Firewall. What’s the url of the website?

Comment: The url is: Upmostly.com

Comment: worked fine from my iPhone on LTE (Verizon).

Comment: @Asdfg Interesting. It's not working for me in the UK.

Comment: Perhaps your provider's LTE is IPv6 only?

Comment: May be try creating a hotspot and connect your laptop to it. Then try dnslookup or other commands to see where you are getting blocked.